# TabBarController viewDidAppear not called when presented view controller dismissed

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I am trying present a navigation controller with UITabBarController, I am confused why UITabBarController's viewDidAppear is not called again after the navigation controller dismissed. How can I manage to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Change presentation style to `currentContext`. For example:

```swift
let controller = ViewController()
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext //<-- Add this line
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Seems not working